# In pandas subtract date from series of date to get series of number of days

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

In my CSV file I have a column with date and time with the format 6/1/2019 12:00:00 AM.
My requirement is to remove time from all rows, then row will have only date. After this I have to subtract all rows from base date 1/1/2019 so the row should have only number of days. Here for e.g if we subtract 6/1/2019 from 1/1/2019 the row will have the value 6.

I tried below code to remove time.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', header = 0)
from datetime import datetime,date
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.date
```

How to subtract date 1/1/2019 from each row in the column and get the days in number using pandas and  python datetime library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove times by [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) from datetimes (convert them to `00:00:00`) and subtract datetime, last convert output timedeltas to days by [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', header = 0, parse_dates=['date'])

df['days'] = df['date'].dt.floor('d').sub(pd.Timestamp('2019-01-01')).dt.days
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2019-01-06 12:00:00', periods=10)})

df['days'] = df['date'].dt.floor('d').sub(pd.Timestamp('2019-01-01')).dt.days
print (df)
                 date  days
0 2019-01-06 12:00:00     5
1 2019-01-07 12:00:00     6
2 2019-01-08 12:00:00     7
3 2019-01-09 12:00:00     8
4 2019-01-10 12:00:00     9
5 2019-01-11 12:00:00    10
6 2019-01-12 12:00:00    11
7 2019-01-13 12:00:00    12
8 2019-01-14 12:00:00    13
9 2019-01-15 12:00:00    14
```